# Window function to convert n number of rows in a column to one single row

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a requirement to window 25 number of rows in a column into one row in dataframe.

The input data is as shown below.

```
+------+----------+---------------------------------------+
|ID    |TIME      |SGNL                                   |
+------+----------+---------------------------------------+
|00001 |1574360355|{"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360296,"SV":"0.0"}|
|00001 |1574360355|{"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360296,"SV":"0.0"}|
|00001 |1574360355|{"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360296,"SV":"0.0"}|
|00001 |1574360355|{"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360297,"SV":"0.0"}|
|00002 |1574360355|{"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360297,"SV":"0.0"}|
|00002 |1574360355|{"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360297,"SV":"0.0"}|
|00002 |1574360355|{"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360298,"SV":"0.0"}|
+------+----------+---------------------------------------+
```

I have to apply window function here to take 25 SGNL for a particular ID and sorted in time in a single row.
I have done windowing for partitioning the dataframe with ID and sorting in TIME.
Now I have to get the data as below.

```
+------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|DTC   |DTCTS     |SGNL                                                                                                                                                           |
+------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|00001 |1574360355|{"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360296,"SV":"0.0"},{"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360296,"SV":"0.0"},{"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360296,"SV":"0.0"},{"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360297,"SV":"0.0"}|
|00002 |1574360355|{"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360297,"SV":"0.0"},{"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360297,"SV":"0.0"},{"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360298,"SV":"0.0"}                                        |
+------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

First 25 rows in SGNL column for a particular partition should be combined in a single row as shown above. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

**Updated answer (2)** :

```
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

  val df = (Seq(
  ("00002",1574360355,"""{"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360297,"SV":"0.0"}"""),
  ("00002",1574360355,"""{"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360297,"SV":"0.0"}"""),
  ("00002",1574360355,"""{"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360298,"SV":"0.0"}""")
) ++ (1 to 51).map{_ => ("00001",1574360355,"""{"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360296,"SV":"0.0"}""")})
.toDF("ID", "TIME", "SGNL")
.withColumn("rownum", row_number().over(Window.partitionBy($"ID").orderBy($"TIME")))

df.groupBy($"ID", (($"rownum"-1)/25).cast(IntegerType).as("by25"))
.agg(min($"TIME"), collect_list($"SGNL"))
.drop("by25")
.toDF("DTC","DTCTS","SGNL")
.show(false)

+-----+----+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|DTC  |by25|DTCTS     |SGNL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             |
+-----+----+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|00001|0   |1574360355|[{"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360296,"SV":"0.0"}, {"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360296,"SV":"0.0"}, {"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360296,"SV":"0.0"}, {"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360296,"SV":"0.0"}, {"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360296,"SV":"0.0"}, {"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360296,"SV":"0.0"}, {"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360296,"SV":"0.0"}, {"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360296,"SV":"0.0"}, {"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360296,"SV":"0.0"}, {"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360296,"SV":"0.0"}, {"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360296,"SV":"0.0"}, {"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360296,"SV":"0.0"}, {"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360296,"SV":"0.0"}, {"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360296,"SV":"0.0"}, {"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360296,"SV":"0.0"}, {"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360296,"SV":"0.0"}, {"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360296,"SV":"0.0"}, {"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360296,"SV":"0.0"}, {"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360296,"SV":"0.0"}, {"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360296,"SV":"0.0"}, {"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360296,"SV":"0.0"}, {"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360296,"SV":"0.0"}, {"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360296,"SV":"0.0"}, {"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360296,"SV":"0.0"}, {"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360296,"SV":"0.0"}]|
|00001|1   |1574360355|[{"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360296,"SV":"0.0"}, {"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360296,"SV":"0.0"}, {"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360296,"SV":"0.0"}, {"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360296,"SV":"0.0"}, {"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360296,"SV":"0.0"}, {"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360296,"SV":"0.0"}, {"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360296,"SV":"0.0"}, {"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360296,"SV":"0.0"}, {"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360296,"SV":"0.0"}, {"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360296,"SV":"0.0"}, {"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360296,"SV":"0.0"}, {"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360296,"SV":"0.0"}, {"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360296,"SV":"0.0"}, {"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360296,"SV":"0.0"}, {"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360296,"SV":"0.0"}, {"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360296,"SV":"0.0"}, {"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360296,"SV":"0.0"}, {"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360296,"SV":"0.0"}, {"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360296,"SV":"0.0"}, {"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360296,"SV":"0.0"}, {"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360296,"SV":"0.0"}, {"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360296,"SV":"0.0"}, {"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360296,"SV":"0.0"}, {"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360296,"SV":"0.0"}, {"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360296,"SV":"0.0"}]|
|00001|2   |1574360355|[{"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360296,"SV":"0.0"}]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        |
|00002|0   |1574360355|[{"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360297,"SV":"0.0"}, {"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360297,"SV":"0.0"}, {"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360298,"SV":"0.0"}]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      |
+-----+----+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Note that the result is now an array.

Comment: I wanted all the columns -1st 25 in one row next 25 in another and so on..
where clause used here will give access to only first 25 rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 Window-Function to implement your requirement:

```
val df = Seq(
  ("00001",1574360355,"""{"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360296,"SV":"0.0"}"""),
  ("00001",1574360355,"""{"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360296,"SV":"0.0"}"""),
  ("00001",1574360355,"""{"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360296,"SV":"0.0"}"""),
  ("00001",1574360355,"""{"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360297,"SV":"0.0"}"""),
  ("00002",1574360355,"""{"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360297,"SV":"0.0"}"""),
  ("00002",1574360355,"""{"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360297,"SV":"0.0"}"""),
  ("00002",1574360355,"""{"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360298,"SV":"0.0"}""")
).toDF("ID", "TIME", "SGNL")

val win =Window.partitionBy($"ID").orderBy($"TIME")

df
  .withColumn("rnb",row_number().over(win))
  .where($"rnb"<=25) // limit to first 25 rows
  .withColumn("SGNL",collect_list($"SGNL").over(win))
  .where($"rnb"===1) // collapse to 1 record per ID
  .withColumn("SGNL",concat_ws(",",$"SGNL")) // convert array to single string
  .drop($"rnb")
  .show()
```

gives:

```
+-----+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|ID   |TIME      |SGNL                                                                                                                                                           |
+-----+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|00001|1574360355|{"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360296,"SV":"0.0"},{"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360296,"SV":"0.0"},{"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360296,"SV":"0.0"},{"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360297,"SV":"0.0"}|
|00002|1574360355|{"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360297,"SV":"0.0"},{"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360297,"SV":"0.0"},{"SN":"Acc","ST":1574360298,"SV":"0.0"}                                        |
+-----+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Note that `Time` now represents the minimum `Time` of your aggregated records. If you want the maximum `Time`, you would need another window function to find the max `rnb` and then filter for that